# Prepending/appending values returned in Google Sheets Select Query

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I have a query like this:

```
=query(Orders,"select A,B,C WHERE C = 'Open'")
```

Which returns data, e.g

```
1234,test@email.com,Open
```

I'd like to prepend a string to the final value, so that it displays:

```
1234,test@email.com,Status:Open
```

Is there a way to do this within the Query or via some other method?

Answer (score 1):

Try [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215?hl=en):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(query(Orders,"select A,B,C WHERE C = 'Open'"),"Open","Status:Open")
```

[image]

Comment: Ah thanks. I realise I've posed the question incorrectly - the value I want to modify is not the first one. Have amended the question, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following formula *(provided your data is in 3 separate columns)*

```
=QUERY({A1:B,ARRAYFORMULA("Status:"&C1:C)}, 
          "select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col3='Status:Open' ",0)
```

[image]